# SSO: Who is the idp (identity provider) for Google Apps?

Tags: authentication, sso

If I am a user for different Google Apps. Google Apps (gmail, google calender, games logging in using Google email account, etc.) are different service providers. Who will be the identity provider (idp)? Is it Google an idp as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, yes. Any Google-based app uses a Google Id for authentication. As such, they are their own IdP.

You can additionally federate to Google with your own IdP as well if you are an enterprise user. It would work along the lines of:

```
Your IdP => Google Id (gIdP) => GMail
```

Comment: could you explain the relation between "own idp" and google idp? Btw, i find there is sso software (e.g. miniorange) allows users residing in any SAML 2.0 compliant idps. they r different cases, right?

Comment: Instead of having Google do the actual authentication of a user, they can hand it off to your IdP via SAML and you do the auth however you want. In that case your IdP is the IdP, and Google ends up as a service provider.

Comment: this is typically called "SSO Federation", i.e. a federated circle of trust between your company (the Identity Provider) and google services (the Service Provider).